# Connect to Postgres for live data

Tags: database, postgresql, odbc, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

Connect to postgres DB from Power BI to get live data - get updated data from db without refresh schedule.

Hi,
I wanted to connect to postgres DB from Power BI. I shoud be able to get live data from postgres. When I am trying to connect to Postgres db, I am getting the following error:

`An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.` 
Any suggestions to get live data from postgres db to power BI would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, use a valid certificate on the PostgreSQL server. See the documentation.